# Connection timed out on port

Tags: java, tomcat, system, httpurlconnection

I have an application running on Apache Tomcat, I am getting a `connection timed out` error when I try to telnet to that port. Here is the `server.xml` config:

```
<Service name="Catalina">
<!-- Define a non-SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
<Connector port="8868" maxThreads="200" minSpareThreads="25"    maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="true" redirectPort="8804" acceptCount="100" debug="0" connectionTimeout="60000" disableUploadTimeout="true"/>
```

When I do `netstat -tupln`, it shows that the port is listening:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :8868

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8868                0.0.0.0:*                    LISTEN      15629/java
```

I am able to ping the IP address, but when I do a telnet to the port I get a connection timed out. I don't think it is a firewall issue because I ran `service iptables status` and got

```
iptables: Firewall is not running.
```

same thing with `service ip6tables status`

```
ip6tables: Firewall is not running.
```

Comment: telnet command please? i've tested with a local tomcat and telne connects at first try

Comment: telnet 10.16.137.16 8868

Comment: hmm i did the telnet from the local machine and was able to connect, but when i telnet from a remote machine i still get connection timed out

Comment: Looks like something outside tomcat is blocking your telnet command. Could you run [nmap](http://nmap.org/) from the remote machine?

Comment: i am able to nmap to the host, when i try to include the port i get

Comment: Invalid target host specification: 8868. Same thing as telnet

Comment: Is the remote machine in the same subnet? Can you ping this machine from the remote machine? Do you have some evidence this is a Tomcat problem rather than a general network connectivity problem?

Comment: if you simply nmap to the host show it you the port 8868 in the output port list?

Comment: Go to Linux box run command "wget "http://localhost:8868/<pagename like index> and then try "wget "http://<IPADRESS>:8868/<pagename like index>and cehck the  output.

Comment: when i nmap to the hostthis is what i see                                            Host is up (0.00073s latency).
Not shown: 909 filtered ports, 88 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
Device type: WAP

Comment: i do a ping 10.16.137.16 and get 2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1945ms                                 i do a ping 10.16.137.16 8868 and get 8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7797ms               so it is something with the port. i need to connect to the port from this remote machine because that is where i am monitoring the servers from